# Como obter quantidade de itens de uma ArrayList?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Estou tentando contar quantos itens contém em uma `ArrayList`, já tenho algo pronto:

```
private int quantidadeN = listaNotificacaos.size();
```

Ele deveria guardar a quantidade dentro da variável `quantidadeN`, mas quando eu jogo na página ele traz um resultado 0.

Na página estou chamando com este código:

```
#{notificacaoControle.quantidadeN}
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Já colocou um breakpoint pra ver qual o valor de `listaNotificacaos.size()` ?

Comment: Joguei direto na Front End #{notificacaoControle.listaNotificacoes.size()} e deu certo. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que quando a variável `quantidadeN` foi definida, o size() era igual a 0.

Use a proópria coleção na sua EL:

```
#{notificacaoControle.listaNotificacoes.size()}
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado